# Using BufferedReader to read lines of a file into a list

Tags: java, file

To help improve my proficiency with Java, I would like to know how should I close these FileReaders as I have come across multiple answers, and what could I do better with this block of code?

```
/**
 * Returns a Vector<String> object that that can be parsed into classes.
 * The file arugment must specify a realative or aboustle adress to the file.
 * @param file to read
 * @return
 */
public static ArrayList<String> read(File file) {

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    String lineRead;

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ( (lineRead = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                data.add(lineRead);                
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Thank you, I am a noobie to Code Review, so please forgive me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 7, you can make use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which would change the implementation to:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    while ((lineRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
        data.add(lineRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Some other tips:

- Your documentation is not telling the truth and incomplete, you have to add some return documentation. Also, for parameters, the first string represents the name, and what follows is the explanation. So it should be more like e.g. `@param file the file to read all lines from`.
- Return the interface instead of the implementation, i.e. return `List` instead of `ArrayList`, which means you can always change the implementation.
- Never just print the stack trace, wrap and throw an (unchecked) exception or log. For more information as to why, see [why printStackTrace is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice). In case you want to propagate the exception nonetheless, you can wrap it in another exception, e.g.:

  ```
  try {
      ...
  } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
  }
  ```

This example may be used when the method this code is executed in does not declare to throw a checked `Exception`. But it all depends on the case at hand.

- `BufferedReader` has a `lines` method returning all `String` lines as a stream. With this, you could also implement it as follows:

  ```
  return br.lines().collect(toList());
  ```

I statically imported `Collectors#toList`. Notice how this results in a `List` and not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Could you talk about the throwing of an unchecked exception or log a little more?

Comment: You are welcome :) I was updating my answer until I though there must be an answer for this on StackOverflow, so I added a link for clarification. It is explained in depth over there!

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, your call to `fr.close()` has no effect, because `fr` has already been closed by `br.close()`, since `close()` releases all underlying resources, which in this case includes other streams or readers that `br` is wrapped around.
- Also, and more importantly, it is imperative that `br.close()` is called regardless of whether the `try` block succeeds or throws an exception. In your code, if `br.readLine()` throws an exception, the reader will never be closed.

  To rectify this, the call to `br.readLine()` has to go into a `finally` block instead of the `try` block, which would mean that `br` has to be declared outside the `try` block:

  ```java
  BufferedReader br = null; //need to initialize it here, or else the compiler will complain later
  try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
      br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      //...
  } catch (IOException e ) {
      //...
  } finally {
      br.close();
  }
  ```

  And this is what the try-with-resources statement mentioned by Koekje is a shortcut for.